# Is there a way to make a div the same size on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

On occasion it is required that a DIV is a specific size so to ensure that the layout lines up but often it seems impossible to fine the CSS to ensure that it sits correctly in all of the major browsers.

For example this simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5P53V/) shows a few tabs that select the div that is shown below the tabs. To make it look more like you are pulling the section to the surface using the tab it overlaps the section slightly with no lower border so it appears the tab and section are one and the same.

The issue is that the height of the tab must be exact or the illusion is destroyed. With this example the tabs are the correct size in the latest Firefox, Safari (last PC version) & Chrome but a pixel to short in Opera so it doesn't overwrite the top border of the text section (details div) and two pixels to small in IE 10 so there is actually a gap between the tabs and main section.

I know I could create a separate style sheet that only loads for IE and Opera etc but I would rather avoid it if possible as it will increase the work for maintaining the site.

#### HTML from JSFiddle:

```html
<div class="product-details-page">
    <div class="details-tabs">
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="description selected">Description</div>
            <div class="deliveryOptions">Delivery Options</div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="description show">A big description of a product. Might go over several lines and will be very "descriptive".</div>
            <div class="deliveryOptions">We just chuck it in Santa's bag when he isn't looking.. <br>Delivery is only once a year but it's FREE! ;)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS from JSFiddle

```css
.product-details-page .details-tabs {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.product-details-page .details {
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px;
}
.product-details-page .details-tabs .tabs > div {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.product-details-page .details-tabs .tabs > div:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.product-details-page .details > div {
    display: none;
}
.product-details-page .details > div.show {
    display: block;
}
.product-details-page .details-tabs .tabs {
    height: 26px;
}
.product-details-page .details-tabs .tabs .selected {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 7px #FF0000;
    text-shadow: 0 0 7px #FF0000;
}
body {
    font-family:"arial,?helvetica,?sans-serif";
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Oh I did work out that it appears to be the text that is causing the change. If I remove the text and adjust the padding to compensate it seems to work fine in all browsers e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/5P53V/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a fixed `line-height` on your tabs. The default value for `line-height` is browser-specific, and it may cause a slight offset. A typical value would be `1.2`.

In fact, you realised this yourself in your comment ;) It's the text that's to blame, and the above `line-height` should fix it.

Comment: OK this is progress. I updated the line-height to 1.3em and at first I thought it was solved but then I realised that it now works in IE, Firefox and Opera but now Chrome is smaller by one pixel and so is Safari. :(
http://jsfiddle.net/5P53V/2/

Comment: Try `line-height: 16px` - a pixel value might be a good idea for something precise like this. `line-height: 1.2` (note: no unit) is a good idea on the document in general for a more consistent look.

Comment: That's fixed it. Thanks Niet the Dark Absol.
Also thanks for the info on line-height being browser specific that explains lots of issues like this! :)
http://jsfiddle.net/5P53V/3/

Comment: Can you please explain why I should use a document level line-height without specific units when it clearly doesn't solve the consistency issue? Wouldn't it be better to just specify pixels (15px say)?

Comment: It helps. Font rendering in general is not consistent (and is one of the things browsers use to try and be better, by being easier to read and such). Using a unitless line height just helps to standardise at least somewhat.